# ajax call to redirect url in current page without query string

Tags: ajax, query-string

This url pass in map and display route. Problem is in query string. Which is not accept more value, so I want to display in current page without refresh page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('#myMapModal').click(function(){

      var application_id = $('#current_application').val();
      var township_id = $('#current_township').val();
      var ttype = $('#current_ttype').val();

      var url = "/portal/grower-draw-map?application_id="+application_id+"&township_id="+township_id+"&ttype="+ttype;

      $.post(
        url,{type:'POST'},
        function(data){
             window.open(url);      
        });
```

Comment: url is not current page url, its another page url,i want to display this url in current page.